# Openstack SSH keypair (public key) not being authorized or imported into instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, key-pair, openstack-horizon, rdo

Sorry if this post has bad formatting. This is my first question on here. Please let me know how to fix if so.

**Openstack setup with RDO packstack all-in-one. Running on Centos-8-Stream.**

I have imported my public key into Horizon and selected it when creating my instance. Once my instance is created I can ping it fine but I cannot SSH into it. I either get: `Unable to negotiate with .... port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` or the usual:

`ssh: connect to host .... port 22: Connection refused`

When running `openstack console log show testVM` I notice that I get `ci-info: no authorized SSH keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu.` and my public key is not listed like it should be.

I also see `cloud-init[332]: 2022-03-02 21:58:25,772 - util.py[WARNING]: No active metadata service found`.

I figured the metadata agent must have something to do with it so I checked the neutron-ovn-metadata service. It seems to be running like normal.

I also checked the nova-api logs and found the logs below. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my problem or not.

```
-keypairs/openstack_key" status: 200 len: 678 microversion: 2.1 time: 0.548608
2022-03-02 17:23:44.849 4370 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] A recoverable connection/channel error occurred, trying to reconnect: Server unexpectedly closed connection
2022-03-02 17:23:45.219 4370 INFO nova.api.openstack.requestlog [req-44b43c3d-7d2e-4e80-9896-82c8e2c 6d19441e4cdda8a3dd524 f1f9dfa706c546f28b4 - default default] .... "GET /v2.1/f1f9dfa706c546f1a788b4/os-keypairs/openstack_key" status: 200 len: 678 microversion: 2.1 time: 0.375837
```

I am not very familiar with the neutron_ovn_metadata and I have done as much investigating as I can with no luck. If anyone has had a similar problem and could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful.

I can post any other logs or information you need. I posted what I thought was relevant but I may be missing some things.

Comment: Does the VM get an IP from openstack? If the metadata service works it should log the VM's requests (if the VM gets an IP). If it doesn't get an IP you should check the neutron dhcp-agent log and also the image's configuration how an IP is provided (e.g. DHCP). You can also set the designated IP temporarily with `ip a add ...` and then check with curl if the metadata service is reachable.